# tensorflow: Please use `rate` instead of `keep_prob`. Rate should be set to `rate = 1 - keep_prob`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I get this warning most of the time when i define a model using Keras. It seems to somehow come from tensorflow though:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\lenik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3445: calling dropout (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) with keep_prob is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `rate` instead of `keep_prob`. Rate should be set to `rate = 1 - keep_prob`.
```

Is this warning something to worry about?
If yes, how do i solve this problem?

Comment: No, its not something to worry about.

Comment: what is this warning for?

Comment: You need to update keras

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This depreciation warning is due to the Dropout layer in `tf.keras.layers.Dropout`.
To avoid this warning, you need to clearly specify `rate=` in Dropout as: `Dropout(rate=0.2)`.

Earlier it was `keep_prob` and it is now deprecated to `rate` i.e. rate = 1-keep_prob. 

For more, you can check out this tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dropout).

Comment: Its just a warning, it doesn't warn you if you re-run the same code.

Comment: Well, in my case it does.

Comment: @xanjay, I added rate in the dropout layer but still I see this warning!!

Answer (score 7):

Tensorflow is telling you that the argument `keep_prob` is deprecated and that it has been replaced by the argument `rate`.

Now, to achieve the same behavior you have now and remove the warning, you need to replace every occurrence of the `keep_prob` argument with `rate` argument, and pass the value `1-keep_prob`.

Comment: `replace every occurrence`
in which file should i make the replacements?

Comment: Every occurrence you have in your code. If you have no occurrences, then tensorflow code has itself some occurrences. In this last case, you don't need to worry about the warning.

Comment: @Neb, Sorry if this sounds nonsense; I'm just curious because I'm getting the same warning. So if `keep_prob` *is replaced* by `rate` in the installed TensorFlow library, why does the code calling a function with old argument `rate` work?

Comment: @IgNite I'm not sure I understand the question. `rate` is the new argument and `keep_prob` is (or was, cause the question is almost 1 year old) the old one. Calling the function with either `rate` or `keep_prob` argument does not return any error but it will behave differently, that's why I say that to keep the same result while using `rate` argument, you must substitute the value you used for `keep_prob` with `1 -  (that value)`.